# How to set the property value of city from Address bean to the cityname property of person bean

Tags: spring

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean  id="add" class="com.basu.Address">
    <property name="H_NO" value="7"/>
    <property name="city" value="bellary"/>
    <property name="state"  value="karnataka"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="per" class="com.basu.person" >
    <property name="cityname" value="#{add.city}"/> 
    </bean>

</beans>
```

i want ouput(Address Bean) :-

```
7
bellary
karnataka
```

i want ouput(person Bean) :-

```
bellary
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is perfectly fine assuming your getters and setters are named accordingly.

`Address` class

```
public class Address {
    private String H_NO;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    public String getH_NO() {
        return H_NO;
    }
    public void setH_NO(String h_NO) {
        H_NO = h_NO;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

`person` class

```
public class person {
    private String cityname;

    public String getCityname() {
        return cityname;
    }

    public void setCityname(String cityname) {
        this.cityname = cityname;
    }
}
```

Remember that Spring beans follow the naming conventions of Java Beans. You should also follow Java naming conventions. Class names should start with an uppercase letter and use `CamelCase`. `H_NO` not very descriptive. Use `homeNumber` or something similar.

Comment: Yes i kept properties name  same as u mention'd in my bean classes (Address and person)

Comment: there are no error's in my program. i am getting output                                                             7
bellary
karnataka                                                                #{add.city}

Comment: @NBR What I've posted in my answer with your XML configuration works for me. What Spring version are you using?

Comment: i am using Spring 3.0.1 Version